# Going back to a JSP page after a prticular action is being done.

Tags: javascript, jsp, redirect, window.location

I have a JSP page. Let's say page1.jsp. I have some java script code written in Script tags where in i call  particular function inside which i just simply do window.location to some URL(http://localhost:8080/ATT/jsp/page2.jsp) where a particular action is being performed. Now once an action is completed on page2.jsp i want to come back on page1.jsp without any user click event or any other event. Should i do window.location(http://localhost:8080/ATT/jsp/page1.jsp) or is there any other approach i can follow. Please suggest me an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.sendRedirect()`

```
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```

### Example:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/ATT/jsp/page1.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You only other option is `history.back()`